# Easy, straightforward, robust way to make host port available to Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

It is really easy to mount directories into a docker container. How can I just as easily "mount a port into" a docker container?

Example:

I have a MySQL server running on my local machine. To connect to it from a docker container I can mount the mysql.sock socket file into the container. But let's say for some reason (like intending to run a MySQL slave instance) I cannot use mysql.sock to connect and need to use TCP.

How can I accomplish this most easily?

Things to consider:
I may be running Docker natively if I'm using Linux, but I may also be running it in a VM if I'm on Mac or Windows, through Docker Machine or Docker for Mac/Windows (Beta). The answer should handle both scenarios seamlessly, without me as the user having to decide which solution is right depending on my specific Docker setup.
Simply assigning the container to the host network is often not an option, so that's unfortunately not a proper solution.

Potential solution directions:
1) I understand that setting up proper local DNS and making the Docker container (network) talk to it might be a proper, robust solution. If there is such a DNS service that can be set up with 1, max 2 commands and then "just work", that might be something.
2) Essentially what's needed here is that something will listen on a port inside the container and like a sort of proxy route traffic between the TCP/IP participants. There's been [discussion on this closed Docker GH issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143#issuecomment-157719393) that shows some `ip route` command-line magic, but that's a bit too much of a requirement for many people, myself included. But if there was something akin to this that was fully automated while understanding Docker and, again, possible to get up and running with 1-2 commands, that'd be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run your container with `--net=host` option. In this case container will bind to the host's network and will be able to access all the ports on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, Boris. I mentioned in my question that sometimes --net=host is not an option, like when there is other networking going on within the container that I don't want to "leak" to the host. It's a bit like not wanting to mount more files/volumes than necessary into the container, but only what's necessary. Same with ports. --net=host breaks that isolation too much. (Though sometimes it's a perfectly valid and simple solution!)